# applink.c not working after marshalling in C#

Tags: c#, c, openssl, rsa, marshalling

I've got a method that uses `PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey` named `GenerateKeys`

```
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) void GenerateKeys(const char* pcszPassphrase)
{
    const EVP_CIPHER* pCipher = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY* pPrivKey = NULL;
    FILE*     pFile = NULL;
    RSA *rsa = NULL;

    pPrivKey = create_rsa_key();
    if (pPrivKey)
    {
        char buff[MAX_PATH];
        sprintf(buff, "%s%s", currentDirectory, "\\Keys\\prikey.pem");
        if ((pFile = fopen(buff, "wt")) && (pCipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc()))
        {
            rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(pPrivKey);
            if (!PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey(pFile, rsa, pCipher,
                (unsigned char*)pcszPassphrase,
                (int)strlen(pcszPassphrase), NULL, NULL))
            {
                 // Not important code
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

`PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey` method needs **applink.c** code block to works properly so I added it too and everything works fine.

```
#define APPLINK_STDIN   1
#define APPLINK_STDOUT  2
#define APPLINK_STDERR  3
#define APPLINK_FPRINTF 4
#define APPLINK_FGETS   5
#define APPLINK_FREAD   6
#define APPLINK_FWRITE  7
#define APPLINK_FSETMOD 8
#define APPLINK_FEOF    9
#define APPLINK_FCLOSE  10  /* should not be used */

#define APPLINK_FOPEN   11  /* solely for completeness */
#define APPLINK_FSEEK   12
#define APPLINK_FTELL   13
#define APPLINK_FFLUSH  14
#define APPLINK_FERROR  15
#define APPLINK_CLEARERR 16
#define APPLINK_FILENO  17  /* to be used with below */

#define APPLINK_OPEN    18  /* formally can't be used, as flags can vary */
#define APPLINK_READ    19
#define APPLINK_WRITE   20
#define APPLINK_LSEEK   21
#define APPLINK_CLOSE   22
#define APPLINK_MAX 22  /* always same as last macro */

static void *app_stdin(void) { return stdin; }
static void *app_stdout(void) { return stdout; }
static void *app_stderr(void) { return stderr; }
static int   app_feof(FILE *fp) { return feof(fp); }
static int   app_ferror(FILE *fp) { return ferror(fp); }
static void  app_clearerr(FILE *fp) { clearerr(fp); }
static int   app_fileno(FILE *fp) { return _fileno(fp); }
static int   app_fsetmod(FILE *fp, char mod)
{
    return _setmode(_fileno(fp), mod == 'b' ? _O_BINARY : _O_TEXT);
}

extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport)
    void **
    OPENSSL_Applink()
{
    static int once = 1;
    static void *OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_MAX + 1] = { (void *)APPLINK_MAX };

    if (once)
    {
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDIN] = app_stdin;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDOUT] = app_stdout;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_STDERR] = app_stderr;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FPRINTF] = fprintf;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FGETS] = fgets;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FREAD] = fread;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FWRITE] = fwrite;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FSETMOD] = app_fsetmod;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FEOF] = app_feof;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FCLOSE] = fclose;

        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FOPEN] = fopen;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FSEEK] = fseek;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FTELL] = ftell;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FFLUSH] = fflush;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FERROR] = app_ferror;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_CLEARERR] = app_clearerr;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_FILENO] = app_fileno;

        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_OPEN] = _open;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_READ] = _read;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_WRITE] = _write;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_LSEEK] = _lseek;
        OPENSSL_ApplinkTable[APPLINK_CLOSE] = _close;

        once = 0;
    }

    return OPENSSL_ApplinkTable;
}
}
```

The problem is I want to use this code in **C#** .After marshalling and calling the `GenerateKeys` method, the **C#** app closes in `PEM_write_RSAPrivateKey` line with this error message:

**OPENSSL_Uplink(0F3C26E0,08): no OPENSSL_Applink**

And its the same error that occured if I don't include **applink.c** in my **C** code
It seems that the problem is `OPENSSL_Applink` function is `extern` method itself but I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: di you try [this](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/OPENSSL-Uplink-0099E000-07-no-OPENSSL-Applink-td20125.html) ?

Comment: @saygins Yes not working